# I want to replace first 2 digits of number by XXX in angular template

Tags: angular

I have inputs like 999,9999,10999. I want to replace first digits except last two by XXX in angular template.
That is 999 should become X99,9999 should XX99 and 10999 should XXX99.

How to do that is there any pipe?

Comment: "I have inputs" - so question is about input or output? Pipe works with output not input elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a single line transform:

```
@Pipe({
  pure: true,
  name: 'xMask'
})
export class XMaskPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return `${'X'.repeat(value.length - 2)}${value.slice(-2)}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use this one if you only want XXX as replacement. If you want indian currency combined with XXX as replacement then you will need some more code.

Comment: I will mark this one as accepted answer because I did not asked for indian currency and XXX as replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do with a Pipe,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'specialPipe'
})
export class specialPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): string {
    let newVal = value.replace(/\d{2}$/, 'XX');
    return newVal;
  }
  
}
```

and use it as,

```
<hello name="{{ name1 |specialPipe }}"></hello>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbthvc?file=src%2Fapp%2FspecialPipe.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

**I writed my own pipe**

Since I am from india there is another code which will convert input to indian currency format. (You can remove that part if it is not necessary for you.)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'xMask'
})
export class XMaskPipe implements PipeTransform {

 transform(value: number): any {

if ((!isNaN(value)) && (value != 0)) {
  var currencySymbol = '₹';
  //var output = Number(input).toLocaleString('en-IN');   <-- This method is not working fine in all browsers!           
  var result = value.toString().split('.');

  var lastThree = result[0].substring(result[0].length - 3);
  var otherNumbers = result[0].substring(0, result[0].length - 3);
  if (otherNumbers != '')
    lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
  var output = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;

  if (result.length > 1) {
    output += "." + result[1];
  }

  const visibleDigits = 2;
  let maskedSection = output.slice(0, -visibleDigits);
  let visibleSection = output.slice(-visibleDigits);
  return currencySymbol + maskedSection.replace(/./g, 'X') + visibleSection;
    }

  }



}
```